# How would ethereum personal accounts helpful?

Tags: private-blockchain, coinbase

I have setup ethereum server node and created one test network. started mining, ether is generating in eth.accounts[0]. i have follwoing questions.

1. How multi accounts(eth.accounts[0], eth.accounts[1],...) will helpful?
2. if i do any transaction by account, accounts should have ether. So one account is enough for one node.
3. How make my customer do transaction through my node? should i create each account for them?
4. if i create each account for my customer, then how can they get ether in their account? should transfer ether from coinbase accounts to other accounts?

Comment: Depending on your location if you manage funds on behalf of users you might be subject to more strict regulations (like KYC o AML). It is better if each user manage its own funds.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for replay.  "It is better if each user manage its own funds." Can you please explain detail?

Comment: Each user has to manage its own wallet. For example they can use a hardware wallet, an online wallet from an exchange, or an application like MyEtherWallet.

Comment: Can you share any tutorial how to create online wallet  and hardware wallet please?